# dispy sample program hangs

Tags: python-3.x, dispy

**TL;DR:** I can't get the most basic `dispy` sample code to run properly.  Why not?

**The details:**

I'm trying to get into distributed processing in python, and thought the [dispy](http://dispy.sourceforge.net/dispy.html) library sounded interesting, due to the comprehensive feature set.

However, I've been trying to follow their basic canonical program example, and I'm getting nowhere.

- I've installed dispy (`python -m pip install dispy`)
- I went on to another machine with the same subnet address and ran `python dispynode.py`.  It seems to work, as I get the following output:

  > 2016-06-14 10:33:38 dispynode - dispynode version 4.6.14
  >   2016-06-14 10:33:38 asyncoro - version 4.1 with epoll I/O notifier
  >   2016-06-14 10:33:38 dispynode - serving 8 cpus at 10.0.48.54:51348
  >
  > Enter "quit" or "exit" to terminate dispynode,   "stop" to stop
  >   service, "start" to restart service,   "cpus" to change CPUs used,
  >   anything else to get status:
- Back on my client machine, I run the sample code downloaded from http://dispy.sourceforge.net/_downloads/sample.py, copied here:

```
# function 'compute' is distributed and executed with arguments
# supplied with 'cluster.submit' below
def compute(n):
    import time, socket
    time.sleep(n)
    host = socket.gethostname()
    return (host, n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # executed on client only; variables created below, including modules imported,
    # are not available in job computations
    import dispy, random
    # distribute 'compute' to nodes; 'compute' does not have any dependencies (needed from client)
    cluster = dispy.JobCluster(compute)
    # run 'compute' with 20 random numbers on available CPUs
    jobs = []
    for i in range(20):
        job = cluster.submit(random.randint(5,20))
        job.id = i # associate an ID to identify jobs (if needed later)
        jobs.append(job)
    # cluster.wait() # waits until all jobs finish
    for job in jobs:
        host, n = job() # waits for job to finish and returns results
        print('%s executed job %s at %s with %s' % (host, job.id, job.start_time, n))
        # other fields of 'job' that may be useful:
        # job.stdout, job.stderr, job.exception, job.ip_addr, job.end_time
    cluster.print_status()  # shows which nodes executed how many jobs etc.
```

When I run this (`python sample.py`), it just hangs.  Debugging through pdb, I see it eventually is hanging at `dispy/__init__.py(117)__call__()`.  The line reads `self.finish.wait()`.  finish is just a python thread, as `wait()` then goes into `lib/python3.5/threading.py(531)wait()`.  It hangs once it hits the wait.

I've tried running dispynode on the client machine and gotten the same results.  I've tried a lot of variants of passing nodes into the creation of the cluster, e.g:

```
cluster = dispy.JobCluster(compute, nodes=['localhost'])
cluster = dispy.JobCluster(compute, nodes=['*'])
cluster = dispy.JobCluster(compute, nodes=[<hostname of the remote node running the client>])
```

I've tried running with the `cluster.wait()` line uncommented, and got the same results.

When I added logging (`cluster = dispy.JobCluster(compute, loglevel = 10)`), I got the following output on the client side:

> 2016-06-14 10:27:01 asyncoro - version 4.1 with epoll I/O notifier
>   2016-06-14 10:27:01 dispy - dispy client at :51347 
>   2016-06-14 10:27:01 dispy - Storing fault recovery information in "_dispy_20160614102701"
>   2016-06-14 10:27:01 dispy - Pending jobs: 0
>   2016-06-14 10:27:01 dispy - Pending jobs: 1
>   2016-06-14 10:27:01 dispy - Pending jobs: 2
>   2016-06-14 10:27:01 dispy - Pending jobs: 3
>   2016-06-14 10:27:01 dispy - Pending jobs: 4
>   2016-06-14 10:27:01 dispy - Pending jobs: 5
>   2016-06-14 10:27:01 dispy - Pending jobs: 6
>   2016-06-14 10:27:01 dispy - Pending jobs: 7
>   2016-06-14 10:27:01 dispy - Pending jobs: 8
>   2016-06-14 10:27:01 dispy - Pending jobs: 9
>   2016-06-14 10:27:01 dispy - Pending jobs: 10

This doesn't seem unexpected, but doesn't help me figure out why the jobs aren't running.

For what it's worth, here's _dispy_20160614102701.bak:

> '_cluster', (0, 207)
>   'compute_1465918021755', (512, 85)

and similarly, _dispy_20160614102701.dir:

> '_cluster', (0, 207)
>   'compute_1465918021755', (512, 85)

I'm out of guesses, unless I'm using an unstable version.

Comment: I also have this type of problem. I would like to know if there is a solution to this problem?

Comment: I haven't found one.  In fact, I gave up on dispy, so I didn't even bother putting a bounty on this.  I also tried [scoop](https://github.com/soravux/scoop), which on the surface does exactly what I need, but it had a very weird, [arbitrary limit for the maximum number of processors I could usefully add](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scoop-users/WlmqPzlsdec).  I've given up, and decided to use basic popen of ssh, and write my own scheduler.

Comment: @ThomasGuenet You made a suggested edit that I'm going to reject.  The edit is inappropriate, because you're changing what I actually said I did.  I did run `python dispy.py`, not just `dispy.py`.  There is a difference in how they run, in that your way is as a module.  That difference _might_ be why the program was hanging.  So your edit is inappropriate, but it may make a good answer.  Write it up as an answer, showing how running just `dispy.py` instead of `python dispy.py` would fix the problem.  If you show it convincingly, you'll have answered this question.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I suggested you change `python dispynode.py` executed from shell to `dispynode.py` directly : this commande makes it possible to launch jobs on the node. I have been using dispy yesterday and was experiencing the same issue and solve it today on my computer. I just don't know if it's the same issue you have. I will post it.

Answer (score 1):

When first setting up and using dispy on a network, I found that I had to specify the client node IP when creating the job cluster, see below:

```
cluster = dispy.JobCluster(compute, ip_addr=your_ip_address_here)
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just running sample.py on your client, change the following in your main statement:

cluster = dispy.JobCluster(compute, nodes=['nodeip_1','nodeip_2',.....,'nodeip_n])

Then run it in your IDE, or via shell.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I had tried `nodes=['nodename']` before, and it didn't work.  Based on your suggestion, I tried `nodes=['nodeip']`, and it still hangs.  For some reason, it's never communicating with the client.

Comment: If your cluster is on the same local network.  On the node try launching the dispynode script this way.

python dispynode.py -i pcname(or ip address)

Then run the script as I described in the previous comment above.

Comment: Using either of those gives me `OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address` (in line 252 of dispynode.py: slf.tcp_sock.bind((ip_addr, node_port)).

Answer (score 0):

Before executing `python sample.py`, `dispynode.py` should still be running on the localhost or the other machine (notice the other machine should be in the same network if you do not want to specify complex options).

I was experiencing the same issue and solved it this way :

- open a terminal and execute : `$ dispynode.py` (do not terminate it)
- open a second terminal and execute : `$ python sample.py`

Do not forget function *compute* consists in waiting a certain time, outputs should appear at least 20 seconds after executing sample.py.

Comment: Well, it was worth a shot, but seems to not matter whether I used `python dispynode.py` or just `dispynode.py`.  I get the same result with my client - it hangs in the wait() condition.  I tried without setting nodes on the cluster, and with setting nodes to both ['hostname'] and ['hostip'].  In all cases, I get the same results with `dispynode.py` as I did with `python dispynode.py`.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
python /home/$user_name/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dispy/dispynode.py
```

```
python sample.py
```

It worked for me